# matplotlib plotting a line which makes fixed angle with x-axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have a fixed point, and I want to draw a line which goes through this fixed point, and also makes 45 degrees angle i.e. slope 1 with the x-axis.

How can i do it with matplotlib ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done setting the aspect ratio of the plot to 'equal' and using the right coordinates, for instance (you can also use `ax.set_aspect`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = [1,2]
ys = [0,1]

ax = plt.subplot(aspect='equal')
ax.plot(xs, ys, '-')
ax.set_xlim(0,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)

plt.show()
```